# special chars not showing correctly in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer

I have an odd problem in IE with special chars passed to my webservice in C#. In other browsers it works but on IE I have problems with passing special chars to my webservice.

I have an input field where users can search for projects. These projects can contain é/è/à... 
In javascript everything is fine but when I debug in C# my é is returned as li� instead of liè...

In other browsers all works fine it is only an IE problem. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you specified the proper HTML document encoding, like '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />' as well as proper doctype, like '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'?

Comment: What is your encoding? This seems like an encoding problem.

Comment: Make sure that you set your character encoding to UTF-8

Comment: My encoding is UTF-8 and it only happens in IE.

Comment: Even when I escape my special chars in javascript the result is �